# Spring-boot HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException is not getting caught by @ExceptionHandler in same controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exceptionhandler

In my spring boot application, I have a controller for post request which produces and consumes JSON request and I have defined @ExceptionHandler for this controller with HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException for catching HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException(406 status code) exceptions.

Now whenever I call the post request with a wrong header of ACCEPT such as application/pdf, the defined exception does not get called.

I don't want to define ControllerAdvice since I would like to throw a specific error for this controller.

code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/school")
public class SchoolCotroller {

    @Autowired
    private SchoolService schoolService;

    @PostMapping(produces = "Application/Json", consumes = "Application/Json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public School postData(@Valid @RequestBody School school)  {

       return  schoolService.save(school);

    }
 @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
    String handleMediaTypeNotAcceptable(
            final HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException exception,
            final NativeWebRequest request) {
        return "acceptable MIME type:" + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
        }
}
```

curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/school' \
--header 'Accept: application/pdf' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "studentName":"mayank",
    "course":1,
    "teacher":"e",
    "id":1
}'
```

So whenever I call this Curl request I get default bad request response with console log as "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]" but it does not call the ExceptionHandler method.

Why is it not calling the required ExceptionHandler method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe springboot is having trouble recognizing the consumes and produces type as `application/json` since you provided it as `"Application/Json"` at your endpoint.
Try the following code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/school")
public class SchoolCotroller {

    @Autowired
    private SchoolService schoolService;

    @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public School postData(@Valid @RequestBody School school)  {

       return  schoolService.save(school);

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
    String handleMediaTypeNotAcceptable(
            final HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException exception,
            final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "acceptable MIME type:" + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives the same thing even after changing produces to  "MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE "

Comment: @MayankGoyal I have updated my answer could you please check again with this code.

Comment: tried with the above code but no luck. Another interested thing is that if I add @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) instead of @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)  then, also it does not invoke that method either.

Comment: You're missing an @ControllerAdvice

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue.
I added Content-Type header as MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE before throwing the error as HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE and it's working.